# How to split a string of Python source code into Python "statements"?

Tags: python, parsing

Given a string `s` containing (syntactically valid) Python source code, how can I split `s` into an array whose elements are the strings corresponding to the Python "statements" in `s`?

I put scare-quotes around "statements" because this term does not capture exactly what I'm looking for.  Rather than trying to come up with a more accurate wording, here's an example.  Compare the following two ipython interactions:

```
In [1]: if 1 > 0:
......: pass
......: 

In [2]: if 1 > 0
  File "<ipython-input-1082-0b411f095922>", line 1
    if 1 > 0
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the first interaction, after the first `[RETURN]` statement, ipython processes the input `if 1 > 0:` without objection, even though it is still incomplete (i.e. it is not a full Python statement).  In contrast, in the second interaction, the input is not only incomplete (in this sense), but also not acceptable to ipython.

As a second, more complete example, suppose the file `foo.py` contains the following Python source code:

```
def print_vertically(s):
    '''A pretty useless procedure.

    Prints the characters in its argument one per line.  
    '''

    for c in s:
        print c

greeting = ('hello '
            'world'.
            upper())

print_vertically(greeting)
```

Now, if I ran the following snippet, featuring the desired `split_python_source` function:

```
src = open('foo.py').read()
for i, s in enumerate(split_python_source(src)):
    print '%d. >>>%s<<<' % (i, s)
```

the output would look like this:

```
0. >>>def print_vertically(s):<<<
1. >>>    '''A pretty useless procedure.

    Prints the characters in its argument one per line.
    '''<<<
2. >>>    for c in s:<<<
3. >>>        print c<<<
4. >>>greeting = ('hello '
            'world'.
            upper())<<<
5. >>>print_vertically(greeting)<<<
```

As you can see, in this splitting, `for c in s:` (for example) gets assigned to its own item, rather being part of some "compound statement."

In fact, I don't have a very precise specification for how the splitting should be done, as long as it is done "at the joints" (like ipython does).

Comment: I'm pretty sure IPython doesn't separate anything, just looks at indentation level and trailing `:` to know when to stop.

Comment: @Hyperboreus AST would work, but it doesn't give enough information, and even what it does give can be wrong due to [**bugs**](http://bugs.python.org/issue16806)...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the internals of the Python lexer (though almost certainly many people on SO are :), but my guess is that you're basically looking for lines, with one important exception : paired open-close delimiters that can span multiple lines.

As a quick and dirty first pass, you might be able to start with something that splits a piece of code on newlines, and then you could merge successive lines that are found to contain paired delimiters -- parentheses `()`, braces `{}`, brackets `[]`, and quotes `''`, `''' '''` are the ones that come to mind.